# Unsorting files in os.listdir()

Tags: python, python-3.x, listdir

In the `os.listdir()` function when I try to get my files it sorts all my files automatically without me giving any sort function.

Is there any way to get the default output without sorted one?

Comment: What exactly do you consider as the default output?

Comment: Given what you consider the default option, you can use `os.stat` (for each file in `os.listdir`) to get the size, atime, ctime, mtime, etc.  Then sort accordingly.  Yes, it’s a long-winded approach, but might get you what you’re after.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) says:

> The list is in arbitrary order

There is no way to "unsort" this. That it appears to be sorted in your case is coincidence, it might as well not be.

In case of CPython, the `listdir` function is not even defined in the `os` module itself, it just forwards the corresponding function from either the `nt` or the `posix` module, depending on which OS you are using.

As an example, you can see the source code of the POSIX version here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5efb1a77e75648012f8b52960c8637fc296a5c6d/Modules/posixmodule.c#L3739

The order in which the entries are added to the result list is determined by calling the [readdir](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) function repeatedly, which does not specify any order, either:

> The order in which filenames are read by successive calls to
> readdir() depends on the filesystem implementation; it is unlikely
> that the names will be sorted in any fashion.

---

(I can't find the Windows version right now.)

Comment: fwiw, both the `nt` and `posix` module come from `posixmodule.c` so both of them use that implementation -- the windows implementation is directly above that one.  I've also updated your link to be a permalink (on github press `[y]` to get a permalink!)